# Log4j logfile error FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I am trying to write a log4j logfile using Netbeans Java. I succeded writing the log file to C:\tmp\log.txt , but for some reason i have no premission to write it at the root of my project : log.txt.

This is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger = all, FILE
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.txt <- failes

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p](%F:%L) %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=./log.txt
```

`.` represents the current folder (usually the project root folder). Maybe the log file that you set are placed somewhere in root of your drive.

---

> #### This reference may useful for you :
>
> [Where Are Your Log4j Log Files?](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=31)

Comment: @omriman12, Its good practice to specify complete path explicitly to avoid unnecessary frustration.

Comment: @omriman12 You can check the reference that I provided on my updated answer

Comment: this refference seems like what i need but still not working for me. forgot to mention that i am using a webservice

Comment: I don't get idea about the relationship between webservice and log the message. What you have done when you succed to write log on `C:\tmp\log.txt`? Are you use absolute path on the configuration?