# Log4J does not want to create logfile

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my project I use Log4j to process all logging. The config I use:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d - %-5p %-10c - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="file" fileName="logs/TAF_${sys:current_date}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-mm-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %-5p %-10c - %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" level="DEBUG"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="DEBUG"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

The error I get:

```
2018-11-19 16:12:59,531 main ERROR FileManager (logs\TAF_${sys:current_date}.log) java.io.IOException: De syntaxis van de bestandsnaam, mapnaam of volumenaam is onjuist java.io.IOException: De syntaxis van de bestandsnaam, mapnaam of volumenaam is onjuist
at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:432)
at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:142)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:418)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:406)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:180)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:95)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
at nl.*****.Apl.<clinit>(Apl.java:9)

2018-11-19 16:12:59,536 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@1ffaf86] unable to create manager for [logs\TAF_${sys:current_date}.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@6574a52c] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@1ffaf86] unable to create manager for [logs\TAF_${sys:current_date}.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@6574a52c]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
    at nl.*****.Apl.<clinit>(Apl.java:9)

2018-11-19 16:12:59,541 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:235)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
    at nl.******.Apl.<clinit>(Apl.java:9)

2018-11-19 16:12:59,543 main ERROR Null object returned for File in Appenders.
2018-11-19 16:12:59,550 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "file" for logger config "root"
```

The first error is in dutch, which translates to: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".

This Log4J config file is used under an Ubuntu environment and works perfectly. Now I have added a Win10 machine to the pool, but I receive this error.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to make the path absolute, "c:/Project/logs/TAF_${sys:current_date}.log", but it did not solve the problem. Every user has read/write access to the logs directory.

Other stuff I tried:
[Log4j logfile error FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462788/log4j-logfile-error-filenotfoundexception)

@edit:
For what I can see, it looks like log4j is trying to create a file named "TAF_${sys:current_date}.log". That ofcourse doesn't work, because { and } are not valid for filenames. When the "_${sys:current_date}" is removed, I am able to create the log file. How am I able to use the expression again, to add the current date/time?

@edit2:Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629772/filename-with-date-in-log4j). I needed to set the system property "current_date" in the code.

Comment: what is value of **logs**

Comment: while trying absolute path, try replacing `/` with `\\\`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @secretsuperstar. I tried both of them without luck. I found the answer, please see the text.